# Point of intersection of a chord with circle

Tags: circles, conic-sections

If I have a circle  $x^2 + y^2 + 2gx + 2fy + c = 0$, and I need to find point of intersection of a general chord $y = mx + c$ with it how do I approach this?
Also please let me know if same approach will work with other conics(ellipse, parabola etc...)

Comment: Simply substitute $y=mx+c$ and solve the quadratic for values of $x$

Comment: A chord is a line segment between two points on a circle, so two points of intersection.  In any case is $c$ meant to be the same constant value appearing in both the equations of the circle and the line?

Comment: Is it just a coincidence that you used $c$ for both the circle and the chord?

Comment: I mistakenly did that, thank you for assuming them different in your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I have a circle  $x^2 + y^2 + 2gx + 2fy + c = 0$, and I need to find point of intersection of a general chord $y = mx + d$ with it how do I approach this?

You substitute in $y=mx+d$ to get rid of all the $y$s.

$$x^2+(mx+d)^2+2gx+2f(mx+d)+c=0$$

Then you gather all the terms in $x^2$, all the terms in $x$, and all the terms with no $x$ at all, and then you use the quadratic equation to solve for $x$. Then you can put that $x$ value in to get $y$ again. You will get two solutions to the quadratic equation. If there are no real solutions to the quadratic, it means that $y=mx+d$ does not actually intercept the circle. There is also the possibility of only one solution of the quadratic, it is left as an exercise for the reader to figure out when that happens.

> The line $y=mx+d$ only touches the circle.

> Also please let me know if same approach will work with other conics (ellipse, parabola etc...)

Yes, the same approach will work wonders with all of these.

Comment: I like the inclusion of the geometric interpretation of the number of solutions! (+1)